# how To Execute Hadoop Command from Java app remotely

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, hadoop, jsch

Hi I'm triying execute any hadoop command like "hadoop fs -ls" throught a Java app remotely. I have my Java app in my local machine and Hadoop in a VM.

First I make a ssh connection and work. Also I can execute a linux command throught the java code it was working ,but hadoop commands are not working,it throws the following Error .Any idea to Execute hadoop commands?

**this is my jsch program**

```
package com.jsch.test;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class Jschtest {

public static void main(String[] args){

String command="hadoop fs -ls /";
try{         
     String host = "192.168.3.197"; //IP address of the remote server
     String user = "user";        // Username of the remote server
     String password = "HDP123!";  // Password of the remote server

     JSch jsch = new JSch();
     Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
     Properties config = new Properties();
     config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
     session.setConfig(config);;
     session.setPassword(password);
     session.connect();

     Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
     ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
     channel.setInputStream(null);
     ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

     InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();
     channel.connect();

     System.out.println("Channel Connected to machine " + host + " server    
with command: " + command ); 

     try{
         InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(input);
         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
         String line = null;

         while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
             System.out.println(line);
         }
         bufferedReader.close();
         inputReader.close();
     }catch(IOException ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }

     channel.disconnect();
     session.disconnect();
 }catch(Exception ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }




}
}
```

This is my Error Message

Channel Connected to machine 192.168.3.197 server with command: hadoop fs -ls /

**bash: hadoop: command not found**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your bashsrc and add the Hadoop BIN folder path to the PATH variable in the file. 
Run `source ~/.bashrc` command.

Alternatively, you can make the following change to the command variable :

```
command = usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -ls
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error "bash: hadoop: command not found" means. Hadoop is not recognized by the OS

You need to update ".bashrc" file with hadoop home directory